# Strange home key behavior when finishing app

Tags: java, android, android-homebutton

The app I'm making will end with opening the SMS inbox for the user convenience and is at this stage finished. Normally then the back key would go back to the activity but since this is does not make any sense for the user I simply tried to finish the app. This worked perfectly and I even release a version at this stage... however... the home key, who could guess that it is a quite popular thing to press when you don't want that annoying feeling of going backwards in life. And now it got messy... basically if the user press home from the inbox the app i lost in some rather strange way that I don't know if I should call a bug or a security feature. The next time I start the app it will go directly to the new intent (showing the inbox) bypassing my app completely, no onResume or anything. Very bad since my app is overridden and becomes a open the inbox link.

Is there any way to make this work at all?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        finish();

        final Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        smsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        startActivity(smsIntent);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want there are a few things you can try

- add to your root activity in the manifest `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"`
  With this flag your app will start from the root activity whenever relaunch from home.
- add `smsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);`
  This will clear the SMS inbox activity and all activities above it in the task stack when relaunch the app from home.
- add `smsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
  This will clear the SMS inbox activity when relaunch.

Comment: Thank you for the rapid replay but sadly none of them change the behavior. As i try to describe above, I will launch this program and press the button that intent me to the sms inbox and then I press home. The next time I press the icon to launch the app I don't launch it at all, it **completely** bypasses my app and go to the new intent. Thou the problem is that the app doesn't get relaunched at all so clearing it on launch is not possible.

Comment: Your app does get relaunh, it is just that the sms box activity is at the top of your task stack. Do you relaunch your app from home or from Recents (long press home)? And what is your root launch mode?

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about "from home" but I relaunch it from the app drawer. The reason I state that it is not relaunched is that I can not detect a relaunch with either, onCreate, onStart or onResume. The launch mode is standard and I have also tried singleTop with no effect. Would you mind trying the above code yourself, maybe I have messed something up. I'm not a professional programmer but do this project as a hobby. It has however gathered a bounce of users and it feels kind a depressing that I can't solve this you know, like I'm letting them down. =/

Comment: smsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY); fixed it, sorry I didn't check your replay for edits and thank you so very very much. I will try to remember to up vote your answer as soon as humanly possible. Honestly, I have been sort of giving up for several weeks and I have always been reluctant to ask questions here because I don't want to annoy people with double topics but it is often hard to be sure if it hasn't been answered or not so I was more or less ready to throw this project away. On behalf of myself and my users, Thank you again!

Comment: Well I run your code as is and there are problems. I got to the sms box the first time I ran your app. But after relaunching, I got MainActivity again and when click on the button to go to sms box, the app just close and I never got to the sms box. I remove the finish() and then add android:noHistory="true" to your MainActivity manifest and everything works fine.

Comment: Oh, that is strange. =) When I add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY it always works and I can't repeat what you say. However, removing finish results in the back key going back from the sms box to MainActivity.

Comment: Did you add android:noHistory="true" to your MainActivity manifest after removing finish()?

Comment: @AndreasÅberg Even if you cannot upvote you still can mark Hoan's answer as answering your question. What's keeping you from doing so?